# The Fourier transform of a function whose domain is not $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, cylindrical-coordinates

There is a function $f(x)$ whose domain is $\left\{ x \mid x\in [0,\infty), x \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$, and what is the Fourier transform of it? Is it

$$ \tilde{f}(k) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}f(x) \, {\rm d} x ?$$

And how about the inverse Fourier transform? What I'm trying to do is to solve the heat diffusion equation
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=K\triangledown^2 T
$$
in cylindrical coordinates. Assume that the function is independent of $\theta$ and $z$, so I only need to deal with PDE with 2 dimension, and turn into the form of
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=K\left(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right).
$$
Also, the initial condition is
$$
T(r,0)=
\begin{cases}
T_2 & 0 \leq r \leq R\\
T_1 & r \geq R\\
\end{cases}.
$$ I'm trying to solve this equation via Fourier transform, but $r$ is always greater than $0$; thus the domain of the function is $[0,\infty)$. I'm not sure if this function can be transformed. That's why I have this question.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. You can extend $f$ to be zero as you have implicitly done above, but the Fourier transform is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok, I understand it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably the Fourier transform is not the best transform in this case. What PDE are you trying to solve?

Comment: For this domain, you could consider the Laplace transform as well.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the equation, it could help people point you in a sensible direction.

Comment: Depending on the actual function, it might be OK to complete the function like $f(-x)=f(x)$ or $f(-x)=-f(x)$. It really depends on your function and maybe this approach will just make things thicker.

Comment: @md2perpe I've update the question. Thanks for spending time solving my question.

Comment: @PC1  I've update the question. Also, Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @OnurOktay Ok, I would try that. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You can use the 2-dimensional Fourier transform to solve it.